# Change %lu (0x%lx) to %u (0x%x) in VIM?

Tags: search, vim, replace

I am trying to replace %lu (0x%lx) with %u (0x%x) for all occurances in a file.

The following command gives "E488: Trailing Characters" Error.
:%s//\%lu (0x/\%lx)//\%u (0x/\%x)/g

Can some one help?

Comment: `:s/%lu (0x%lx)/%u (0x%x)/`  works fine fo me. Just remove unneccesary slashes from your regexp.

Comment: IIt worked! Thanks a lot Alex